# How to loop a function that displays greeting at different times

Tags: javascript, loops

I am new here and new to js.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to loop the following getGreeting function a certain number of times, say 20. So depending on the time of day you would get 20 good mornings!'s or 20 good afternoon's and so on.

Thank you

```
window.onload = function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = getGreeting(hours);
};

function getGreeting(hours) {
    var greetingText;
    if (hours >=6 && hours < 12) {
        greetingText = "Good morning!";
    } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17) {
        greetingText = "Good afternoon!";
    } else if (hours >= 17 && hours < 23) {
        greetingText = "Good Evening!";
    } else if (hours >= 23 || hours < 6) {
        greetingText = "Go to sleep!";
    }
    return greetingText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i=0;i<21;i++)
{
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = getGreeting(hours);
  // Maybe you want this
  document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML + "\n" + getGreeting(hours); // This will show 20 Greetings in the field
}
```

But what purpose does it serve? you wont even notice the 20 repetitions since you are updating same `greeting` element's InnerHTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so I would need to create 20 more div's in order to actually see 20 greeting appear on a page?